# Handle Worker thread error and result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling, backgroundworker

I have an application that process some work in the worker thread. in the dowork function I am calling a  DAL function. according to the DAL result(successful or fail) I ll go further.Below is the sample code how I want to Implement.

```
MyFunction()
{
    this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
    this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error!=null)
    {
    //operation fail
    }
    else if(e.Result!=null)
    {
    //operation succeed
    }
}
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int result=GetResult(10,0);
    int result2=GetResult(10,5);
}
int GetResult(int number1,int number2)
{
    return a/b;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you facing some problems, something goes wrong?

Comment: Thnx for your reply.I am fail to implement `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` I want to use those result from the do worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not assigning `e.Result` in `backgroundWorker_DoWork` method.

It should be something like:

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = GetResult(10,5);
}
```

Then in the case of error (for example, by `GetResult(10, 0)`) it will be exception text in `e.Error` and result in `e.Result` otherwise - just as you're expecting in your `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` method.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have already tried there is no option e.error in dowork method.

Comment: You don't need to set `e.Error` in `_DoWork`. Just set `e.Result`. BackgroundWorker will set `e.Error` by itself if exception will be thrown during execution.